# Pandas: What determines the return type of DatetimeIndex.intersection?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have two Dataframes with timezone-aware DatetimeIndices, let's call those A und B. There is a difference between the DatetimeIndices, because I converted A to UTC while B is already in UTC and won't let me use `tz_localize` as it's already timezone-aware. A has `dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]'` while for B this field reads `dtype='datetime64[ns]'`

When I intersect them, I get the `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'tz'` error, so the return type is not an DatetimeIndex, but an Index. This is consistent with the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.intersection.html), but I wonder what determines the return type and how I can change it?

```
B = B.tz_localize('UTC')
B = B.tz_convert('UTC')
```

does the trick, but is there a nicer solution?